# Copy constructor Java

Tags: java, constructor

I defined a class called `Node` as

```
private class Node {
      public Node father;
      public JigSaw js;
      public int dist;

      public Node(Node father, JigSaw js, int d){
        this.father = father;
        this.js  = js;
        this.dist = d;
      }
      public Node(Node aux){
        this(aux.father, aux.js, aux.dist);
      }
}
```

But, when I do

```
Node next_n = new Node(prev_n);
```

And change `next_n` contents, `prev_n` changes too!
How can I get these objects unlinked?

Comment: Look up **deep** copy.

Comment: Helped. The trick was that the deep copy wasn't be done for JigSaw class! Not for Node. Thanks,

Comment: No, the problem is that the deep copy was not being done for Node. Re-look at the answers. You need to copy deep within all children of the ultimate parent.